# I want to get column number from stream position (hex editor)

Tags: c#, hex, hex-editors

I have make a method to get to column number in my [wpf hexeditor control](https://github.com/abbaye/WpfHexEditorControl) It's work fine with the property :

> BytePerLine = 16 or 8

But when I use other value, it bug and don't give always the good column number. I need this for color column or get column number when needed for other reason.

**C# CODE:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the column number of the position
/// </summary>

internal int GetColumnNumber(long position)
{
    var line = (double)position / BytePerLine;
    var decPart = line - Math.Truncate(line);

    return (int) decPart * BytePerLine;
}
```

See next image when work good. The column color correctly and i can get the good column number of the SectionStart also when is not in the view.

[image: Work good]

See next image when dosen't work good. The column color not correctly...

Thank for your help ! :)

Comment: Use mod function : return position % BytePerLine;

Comment: Yes i use already : BytePositionInFile % 2 == 0 but it's not work correctly with other value than 8 or 16 :(

Comment: There are other issues.  The mod function is correct so problem with no working correctly with values other than 8 or 16 is some place else in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mistake to use floating point arithmetic here. You can, and should, do all the necessary calculations using integer arithmetic.

For example:

```
static void GetRowCol(long position, long colCount, out long row, out long col)
{
    row = position / colCount;
    col = position % colCount;
}
```